# How to swap between FN and Ctrl keys?

Tags: keyboard, function-keys

I have a Think Pad at work and the keyboard is really killing me (the left Ctrl is not on the most left and it has the FN key there).

I use a lot of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> while writing code and this FN key annoys me (I keep pressing it instead of Ctrl).

Anyway, how to make the FN key the CTRL key?

Comment: Thinkpad BIOS typically gives you option to swap Fn/L_Ctrl...

Comment: I have an HP Envy and the CTRL key broke, so I need an answer to this that is not Thinkpad specific.  Already googled but to no avail.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is a BIOS feature

1. reboot the computer
2. Enter BIOS setup
3. config -> keyboard/mouse -> Fn and Ctrl Key swap

Comment: yes, right-o, +1