# Switch Ctrl <-> Fn keys on Thinkpad

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout, thinkpad

How can I switch the Control key (Ctrl) with the Function key (Fn) on my Thinkpad?
I have Ubuntu 20.04 and Dual Boot (Ubuntu and Windows), so I'm not sure about the option to change it from the BIOS.
I couldn't find a way to do this from the normal settings or in GNOME Tweaks.

Comment: "I'm not sure about the option to change it from the BIOS" – Does that mean... you didn't look in the BIOS? Or you looked and didn't find it? Or you looked, found it, but didn't try it? // The usual way to change this setting is in BIOS. Since the Fn key changes how some keys function, I doubt it can be changed from the OS.

Comment: See [How to swap between FN and Ctrl keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193529/how-to-swap-between-fn-and-ctrl-keys)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: on a Dual Boot, you can enter these settings in the Menu where you choose which OS to boot into. In my case, that is the GRUB menu. There, instead of choosing Windows or Ubuntu, I select the UEFI settings.